# Spring MVC Controller Sends/Receives Data to/from a jsp page which uses ajax

Tags: ajax, jsp, spring-mvc

How can I get a simple message (like msg) from `jsp/ajax` in `spring controller` and return a `response` (like resp) from controller back to the jsp, while jsp could get this response using ajax and show that in a `<div>` ?

Maybe the following sample is incorrect, especially the ajax part, appreciate to modify:

**here is my controller:**

```
    @RequestMapping("/testAjax")
    protected ModelAndView testActiveX(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response){       
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("test_Ajax");
        Date date=new Date();
        model.addObject("date",date.toString());
        return model;
    }
```

**here is my test_Ajax.jsp page:**

```
<html lang="en">
<%@taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<head>
    <spring:url value="/resources/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" var="jqueryJs"></spring:url>
    <script src="${jqueryJs}"></script>
    <script >
        $(document).ready(function($)
        {
            $("#translate").click(translation());
        });
        function translation() {
            var words = $("input").val();
            $.ajax({
                url: '/WEB-INF/jsp/test_Ajax.jsp',
                data: {
                    word: words
                },
                success: function (data) {

                    $("#container").html(data);
                },
                type: 'GET'
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="input" name="inputword"><br/><br/> <-- used to provide msg --%>
<button id="translate">Translate</button><br/><br/>
<div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

As I can see, you have a mistake in the ajax call url, as you are trying to access a jsp inside WEB-INF folder. As you are using spring mvc with a @RequestMapping, you must point the ajax call to the url listened by this mapping.

In your case you must change the url to point the servlet endpoint, which is the actor who serves you the composed html of the view
    $.ajax({
        url: '/testAjax',
        data: {
            word: words
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $("#container").html(data);
        },
        type: 'GET'
    });

Maybe there can be another mistakes as your request mapping can be in a context (so you can put the requestContext concat to the requestmapping url.

Hope this helps

Comment: I remark that this sample may has mistakes. I want to know the solution, please give a sample which run correctly. I mean in first step by clicking on jsp `ajax-based` button, controller get a specified value, and in second step spring controller can manipulate the received data and get back manipulated data to the `jsp page` while it can show using ajax in a <div>.

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted should work with the correct url in the ajax call. Java apps have a context (start of the URI) so you have to be aware to this when telling the url (you can use jstl expressions like ${contextPath} to get this value if you are using a web 3.0 spec).

You can also receive query params (sent via post or get) adding params to the controller method and annotating them with @QueryParam who receives the name of the param to map (this also work with complex json objects if you have a JacksonMapper bean defined in the spring context). So for example. to receive the word string you have to add

```
@QueryParam("word") String word
```

to the method signature.
You can also work directly with the HttpServletRequest in that method and get the content of the param like this:

```
String word = request.getParam("word");
```

inside the controller.

Comment: Give me an example just like my question please. I want to know the complete cycle between jsp and spring mvc through ajax technology.